# How i can select elements for react select on modal imacros

Tags: javascript, reactjs, imacros

I have project is built with ReactJS

I try to select element in select using imacros.

I have code similar of this website https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ first select (States)

i went to select victoria

i have record this code but shi is not work please help me

```
URL GOTO=https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:react-select-2--value-item
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#react-select-2--value-item" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="#react-select-2--option-4" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP POINT="(523,688)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCI missing in your Qt...

Like answered in your parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum:
https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30587&p=83724#p83720

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

'Select "Victoria" in 'States' DDLB:
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#example>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>SPAN:nth-of-type(3)>SPAN" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#react-select-2--option-2" BUTTON=0
```

And if you want to select that Item in the DDLB by its Name...:

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#state-select" CHARS="Vict"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#react-select-2--option-0" BUTTON=0
```

... => From typing "V' or "Vict" or the full Name => "Victoria" becomes the 1st Entry, corresponding to "--option-0" in the Selector...

```
(Tested on iMacros for FF v8.8.2, PM v26.3.3 (=FF47), Win10_x64.)
```

EDIT:
+ More Info and some other Solution(s) also applied to a different Site in the parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum...